# Is this account disabled?

Tags: support

See [What's the difference between "default gateway" and "preferred DNS server"?](https://superuser.com/questions/77914/whats-the-difference-between-default-gateway-and-preferred-dns-server/77916#77916). The username doesn't link to the user account, as it usually happens, and no reputation is shown.

Does this mean the account has been disabled or blocked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, what it means is that the user doesn't have a Super User account. The answer was posted on Server Fault and migrated over to Super User when the question was migrated.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Just for curiosity, does the user lose the reputation he gained because his answer has been voted 14 times, or he will retain it when he creates an account on Super User?

Comment: @kiamlaluno When the user creates a Super User account and links it to his Server Fault account, he will regain ownership of his posts and be able to earn reputation from them. However, I'm uncertain if he will be awarded reputation for votes cast before the account was linked, but that can be fixed with a simple reputation recalc.